# Does apache ignite spring data support order by clause

Tags: ignite

I am trying to apply the order by clause in apache ignite with spring data query
but it's not working for me.

Spring Data Method Signature :

List findByPropertyNameOrderByPropertyName(String propertyName)

Comment: What happens if you run it?

Comment: I just checked that use case and it works as expected. Could you please provide a code that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Now, it's working fine for me. This issue was coming due to cache name which is fixed at configuration level.